# It appears that getElementsByTagName('table') doesn't work properly in IE11. Is there a work around?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, getelementsbytagname

`var tables= dragContainer.getElementsByTagName('table');`

The array returned by this call doesn't have the rows array filled out every time. This works properly in Chrome and IE9, but not in IE11.

Is there a work around I can use? I tried doing the following but it doesn't appear to be working. I'm not quite a javascript expert to tell exactly why but I am going to keep digging for a bit.

I could just pull the rowNodeList and store it, but I want to override the tables[j].rows because there is a large amount of code expecting this sort of structure.

```js
var tables= dragContainer.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
 var rowNodeList = tables[j].getElementsByTagName('tr');
 tables[j].rows.length = 0; //clear array
 
 for (k=0; k < rowNodeList.length; k++) {
  tables[j].rows[k] = rowNodeList[k];
 }    
}
```

EDIT: I just realized since this code is FOSS, I can just link to it.
https://github.com/dbunic/REDIPS_drag/blob/master/redips-drag-source.js#L334

Comment: Where is `tableNodeList` defined? Should it not be `for (i = 0, j = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {`...

Comment: There's no way to add a class on it? Might fix this.

Comment: @War10ck, sorry that was a copy and paste error.

Comment: @RenatoGalvão, good call, lets try that.

Comment: Try printing `console.log(tables)` to see what is returning. As @RenatoGalvão said, try adding a class or an id, it will probably do the job.

Comment: @Zordon, it returns properly except the rows array has 0 elements when it should have 6.

Comment: @RenatoGalvones I tried to use getElementsByClassName, which also have the same issue. The rows array is 0 when it should have 6 elements.

Comment: @user606723 Hmmmm... What about the syntax of the table? Do you have tr's, th's, td's all well formatted/written? 

Put the code on jsfiddle.net it will be faster to identify it.

Comment: @RenatoGalvones Unfortunately it's proprietary code and cannot be placed on fiddler. Perhaps I can come up with an example though. As I said, it works on every browser except IE11

Comment: I get the correct `tr` length in IE11 running this code [http://plnkr.co/edit/8WkE323iI6eF3s7QfxSf?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/8WkE323iI6eF3s7QfxSf?p=preview) I hope I'm following you right.

Comment: @user606723 I understand. Do it with example code though.

Try cleaning out the table, having just a <table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table> and see if the IE11 gets it.

Comment: @Zordon THis is closer to the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/r8cWN69JVGeusb3lRQ3K?p=preview  However, that also works correctly for me as well.

Comment: Since this works in IE11, I don't think I will be able to find a simple example. HRM.. http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/example15/